# Closed Source PHP CMS

Tags: php, cms

Can anyone suggest some good closed source cms based on php? I'm looking around Google but found lists of open source cms but a few closed source cms. And usually they are not based on PHP or the cms is headless and can only store en offer content through an API.

The cms must be closed source, not cloud based, able to create websites and it must be a content-hub. In addition, I want to create content types, such as Author and Page or Blog. Does anyone have a good closed source cms based on php that meets these requirements?

It would be good to get others view on this. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The primary implementation of PHP is as an interpreted language (if you were to compile it, then they would give you binaries and you won't tell they used PHP), if you want PHP software to run on your servers (and not in a third party cloud), what you want is the PHP source code, if they are giving you the source code... then why not make it open source? - I'm unaware of any PHP closed source not cloud based cms solutions, and I don't think there are. Why do you want it closed source anyway?

Comment: I'm doing some research to possible CMS solutions for my business. I have tried a lot of Open Source cms and it's indeed possible to do what I want.  But to get a better picture of the possibilities I also wan't to know something about the closed source cms.

Comment: What is confusing is your specifying PHP as the language. If you want closed source, you are likely not getting access to the code. In that case, what difference does the underlying language make? Perhaps you should investigate something like Microsoft Sharepoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mention by Eric Shain, with a closed source CMS you won't have access to the code base anyways so it's almost pointless looking for some. In any case, the biggest and most successful CMS'es are open source, so I'm guessing what you're looking for are service providers that develop features and tools against CMS'es so as to know what services they can provide, and to show you the power of the platform. Or perhaps you'd like to do a feature comparison.
I believe you can find service providers and consultants for the biggest open source [php CMS'es](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems#PHP) out there and they will almost always match anything a closed source can do for you. I'm assuming there are closed source Php CMS'es here though I haven't come across one so far.

Comment: Just a little nit, but you misspelled my last name.